# Split multi-file post with Javascript before upload

Tags: javascript, html, upload

I understand the HTML/PHP side of a multi-file upload, but I suppose what I'm after is a Javascript solution that separates the files array pre-post and individually sends the files to a separate PHP program to receive upload and success/fail feedback before continuing.  (ie: files[0] -> POST -> Success -> files[1] -> POST -> Success ->etc...)

Here is what I use now for a single file -

```
    function upload(file){
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append("file", document.getElementById(file).files[0]);
        var xmlHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHTTP.open("POST", "uploader.php");
        xmlHTTP.send(data);
    }
```

I realize that the easy way out would be to create multiple file fields, however what I'm trying to do is use `<input type="file" multiple>` from HTML5 to mass-select a list of files at a time.  If I could only separate the files with Javascript, then it would be a simple matter of looping through the above script with an `onreadystatechange` reporting the success/fail each time.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Forgive my tunnel vision, that was extremely simple!  Here's my full code in case it helps someone else out.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="Javascript">
    function multiupload(file){
    count = 0;
    maxcount = document.getElementById(file).files.length;
    alert(maxcount);
    upload(file,count);
    }

    function upload(file,count){
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append("file", document.getElementById(file).files[count]);
        var xmlHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHTTP.open("POST", "uploader.php");
        xmlHTTP.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if (xmlHTTP.readyState == 4 && xmlHTTP.status == 200){
            count = count+1;
            if(count<maxcount){
            upload(file,count);
            }
            }
        }
        xmlHTTP.send(data);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" multiple>
        <input type="button" name="submit" value="Upload" onclick="multiupload('file');void(0);">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can get rid of the `maxcount` logic by just increasing your `count` until `files[count]` returns null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery). You can start uploading the next file in the success handler. That way you can do files[0] -> POST -> Success -> files[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery) -> POST -> Success

Answer (score 3):

To see how many files there are, use `document.getElementById(file).files.length`. Once you've looped that many times, you have uploaded all the files! Here's my sample:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="Javascript">
function multiupload(file){
count = 0;
alert(document.getElementById(file).files.length);

}

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" multiple>
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="Upload" onclick="multiupload('file');void(0);">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

(Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileList)